# How to design Up stair grid layout in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am designing a stair grid for showing the growth of a child in 4 up steps.

What I did is: created four rows containing 4 columns. From the first div, I removed the first three column and put content in fourth. Similarly, on next bottom div I put content in the third column then in next bottom filled the second column.

After all these, I put top margin negative so that it looks like a stair.

I know this is not a good approach. How can I improve that?

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Current code:

```
<!--Here i have used the last column and col-md-9 remains blank-->
<!-- First row --> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-md-auto bg-alert">
        <img src="img/career/info2/4.png" class="img-responsive">      
    </div>
</div>
<!--Here i have used the second last column and col-md-6 remains blank-->
<!-- secondrow --> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:-14rem;">
        <img src="img/career/info2/3.png" class="img-responsive">     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<!--Here i have used second column and  remains blank-->
<!-- Third row -->  
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-md-auto"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-md-auto" style="margin-top:-37rem;">
        <img src="img/career/info2/2.png" class="img-responsive">      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ml-md-auto"></div>
</div>
<!--Here i have used the first column and col-md-9 remains blank-->
<!-- Fourth row --> 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="img/career/info2/1.png" class="img-responsive">      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide your code ?

Comment: Facing issues while adding my code. In a few minutes i will update my code as well

Comment: You need to specify the version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to solve this problem:

You put 4 columns into one single `.row` and then add 3 custom classes to the first 3 columns (`.step-1` / `.step-2` / `.step-3`).

Using `@media (min-width: 768px)` you ensure that those custom classes only kick in on medium (`md`) screens or larger. Then you add `margin-top` to each column as needed to push it down.

On screens that are smaller than `md` the 4 columns will stack up in the right order without any top margins affecting them.

Click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .step-1 {
            margin-top: 150px;
        }
        .step-2 {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
        .step-3 {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 step-1">Step 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 step-2">Step 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 step-3">Step 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Step 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to give you +1. Whenever i will get that much reputation i will give you. Thanks again.